# Combine three SQL queries with keeping orders of the queries without duplicates

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, where-clause, sql-like

I have three queries as follows:

`select * from orders where full_name like 'Mohammed Ali%' order by g_date desc`

This will gives all names starting with Mohammed Ali (10 results)

`select * from orders where full_name like '%Mohammed Ali%' order by g_date desc`

All names have 'Mohammed Ali' in it (20 results)

`select * from orders where full_name like '%Mohammed%Ali%' order by g_date desc`

All names have Mohammed and Ali (100 results)

I would like to get results for all three queries, but the priority for the 1st query then the 2nd, and finally, the last. I don't want duplicate results.

I first did the following:

```
select * from (
select * from orders where full_name like 'Mohammed Ali%'order by g_date desc)
union
select * from (
select * from orders where full_name like '%Mohammed Ali%'order by g_date desc)
union
select * from (select * from orders where full_name like '%Mohammed%Ali%'order by g_date desc)
```

But, I got mixed results from the three queries :( . No duplicates - (100 results)  Great!

Then, I tried the following:

```
select * from (
select *,0 as ord from orders where full_name like 'Mohammed Ali%')
union
select * from (
select *,1 as ord from orders where full_name like '%Mohammed Ali%')
union
select *,2 as ord from (select * from orders where full_name like '%Mohammed%Ali%')
order by ord,g_date desc
```

The first issue was fixed (Great). However, now I have duplicate results (10 + 20 + 100)

How can I get sorted results with no duplicates?

Comment: No UNION needed, simply use the `'%Mohammed%Ali%'` query and have a case expression in the ORDER BY to get the desired result.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: thanks @jarlh, didn't know we can use like in ORDER BY

Comment: @PChemGuy I am sure many people will benefit from my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only condition that you need in the `WHERE` clause is `full_name LIKE '%Mohammed%Ali%'`.

In the `ORDER BY` clause you can sort the returned rows by boolean expressions/conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE full_name LIKE '%Mohammed%Ali%'
ORDER BY full_name LIKE 'Mohammed Ali%' DESC, -- first all names starting with 'Mohammed Ali'
         full_name LIKE '%Mohammed Ali%' DESC; -- then all names containing 'Mohammed Ali'
-- all the other names will be at the bottom of the resultset
```

Answer (score 0):

try a simpel case when

```
with orders (full_name)
as
(
select 'Mohammed Ali'
Union all select 'hMohammed Ali'
Union all select 'Mohammed Ali'
Union all select 'fMohammed Ali'
Union all select 'hMohammed fAlia'
)
select 
    *,
    case when full_name like 'Mohammed Ali%' then 1
    when full_name like '%Mohammed Ali%' then 2
    when full_name like '%Mohammed%Ali%' then 3
    end as ord
from 
    (
        select * from orders where full_name like '%Mohammed%Ali%'
    ) x
order by ord
```